# Finding div width

Tags: css, html

I have three divs. The two smaller ones are inside the same container, the third div.

- The first child div is 350x350 px big.
- The third div is 89% of another container div, meaning I dont know the size of it.
- I want to make the second child div span between the edges of the first child div and the container div.

Basically:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first_child" style="width:350px; height:350px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="second_child" style="width:???px; height:350px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

How do I figure out the width of my `second_child` element if I want the `second_child` element to span precisely between the `first_child` element and the edge of `container`?

Edit:
Uploaded a quickly drawn image. The big black square is `container`, measurements are unknown. The red box is `first_child`, the blue box is `second_child`. I want to find the width for `second_child` so it will stretch from the end of `first_child` to the right edge of `container`.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you draw a picture?

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/3x8aX/)

Comment: Picture uploaded. Hope it clears it up a little.

Comment: @SimonCarlson: So like my link then? [Here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/3x8aX/1/)

Comment: Yes, like that. If I want to eliminate the gap between the 2 child elements, I presume changing `margin-left` to 350 px? Post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @SimonCarlson: Your presumption is correct, I have posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to use some css like so:

```
#container {
    width:89%;
    height:350px;
}
#first_child {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
}
#second_child {
    height:350px;
    margin-left:350px;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3x8aX/3/) (with added styles to see the effect)

Comment: Why is the `margin-left: 350px` on `#second_child` necessary?

Comment: dunno... i did that nearly 3 years ago. If it works for you without it then so be it. Though I expect it was there for some reason back in the day

Answer (score 3):

You can do using CSS `calc()`:

```
#second_child {
   width: -moz-calc(100% - 350px);
   width: -webkit-calc(100% - 350px);
   width: calc(100% - 350px);
}
```

For IE8 and lower you'll have to use jQuery or javascript

Comment: Might be useful to add that it is probably good practice to declare `box-sizing: border-box` on the children, on the merit that paddings, border-widths will add on to the declared width of the element otherwise.

Comment: @Terry You can minus padding as well :) Let's say `calc(100% - 350px - 20px(padding 10px from both sides))`; Anyway, thanks for pointing ;)

Comment: It gets more problematic when your paddings are percentage based ;)

Comment: @ Terry [take a look here](http://jsfiddle.net/MJRNq/) It doesn't matter is it percentages, pixels or em's ;)

Answer (score 1):

A good answer with pure CSS was given above, so I'll just answer the question of "how do I find the width needed?" in javascript.

```
// This is assuming there is no padding.
totalWidth = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
firstChildWidth = document.getElementById('first_child').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('second_child').style.width = (totalWidth - firstChildWidth) + 'px';
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll be going with musefan's answer as its simpler and fixed my problem, but this can be useful in the future. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var containerWidth = $('#container').width();
$('#second_child').width(containerWidth - 350);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with pure css positioning, since you know how big the first child is:

```
#container {
position:relative
}

#first_child {
width:350px;
height:350px
}

#second_child {
height:350px;
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left:350px;
right:0;
}
```

Note that the container div has position:relative. This is necessary to make position:absolute use the top left corner of the container div instead of the body.

Comment: The width of my container is unknown, thats the problem here.

Comment: You don't need to know the width of the container. Only the width of the first child must be known. This is the case (350px). With left:350px (the witdth of the first child) and right:0 you stretch the second child to the width of the container.